# Constant defined inside function is not acceible via class name please see code

Tags: php, class, oop

here the constant is dynamically defined inside the function and i am unable to access it with class name any help i want to make it accessible via class name.
 my constants in functions are coming from Db and i am generating constant from db and i want to access them with class name please tell me what do i do with "define" to make Constants available or class as well

```
    class MyClass {
        public function getsettings(){
            define('myconstant','values');
        }
    }
    echo MyClass::myconstant;
```

Comment: why do you use constant inside a class? you know you can use class properties right?!

Comment: It's most sensible to use class constants in a class, not global constants

Comment: how can i make the class constants?

Answer (score 5):

Function [define()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) will define constant for global scope, no matter where you've called it - it has nothing to do with any class or it's context. To define [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php), you should use `const` keyword:

```
class MyClass 
{
    const myconstant = 'values';
    //..
}
```

Comment: i have to get constant from db and generate with this class

Comment: So this is _not a constant_ then - by definition. Constant is something ..well, _constant_, not something which can be dynamic and depends from runtime condition. Your case will be class property.

Comment: actually list of constant are exist in my database and i have to get and generate those constants , i am doing this with function inside class but unable to access with class name

Comment: This is still violating constant logical meaning. Constant is not something you should define in runtime (in general, even `define()` function is not well). You can use static public properties instead - that will be the best solution.

Comment: actually i have some limitations that why i want to do it like this. my boss want them dynamic with minimum changes in existing project.

Comment: So what will be changes if you'll use static property? You'll still be able to access it via `::` operator

Answer (score 0):

To get `myconstant` in existence you need to call the function `getsettings()`.

Thereafter `myconstant` will be a **global constant** but will not be part of the class i.e. `MyClass`.

Use the following code:

```
class MyClass {
    public function getsettings(){
        define('myconstant','values');
    }
}
$obj=new MyClass;
$obj->getsettings();
echo myconstant;// prints 'values' as you need.
```

Now if you want to use the constant as **associated with the classname** then you must **declare the constant with `const`-keyword**.

But in that case **you must assign a static value** to that constant while declaring it. Hence in your purpose ***you can't use `const`*** as you want to **dynamically assign a value** retrieved from the database to the constant. Hence **you must use the syntax of `define()`** that I have already given in my answer.

### My Suggestion

For your purpose I suggest you to use a variable with `private` access specifier with `static` modifier instead of **constant**. In that case you will be allowed to access or modify them in a privileged way i.e. from inside the **base class** only.

That is actually the need of **OOP** i.e. to put stress on the security of the data(i.e. in terms of **`private`** access specifier).

### Sample code

```
class MyClass {
    private static $constant;
    public function getsettings(){
        //code to access database values...
        self::$constant=$database_val; //$database_val is assigned with values from the database
    }
    public function return_constant()
    {
        return self::$constant;
    }
}
$obj=new MyClass;
$obj->getsettings();
echo $obj->return_constant();
```

Comment: is there any other possibility to use constant with class name ?

Comment: your second suggestion

Comment: @RajeshPaul this is a complete misuse of OOP as well: why whould `getsettings()` be an instance method? And why call a method `return_constant`, when it may return different values [`NULL` if called before `getsettings`, another value if called after]?

Just inject parameters in the object constructor if needed: dependency injection is the way to go in this case.